# Catching Error from SQL Agent Job calling a .exe

Tags: powershell, exception, invoke-command, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I would like to run a .exe from a SQL Server Agent Job.
The .exe is hosted in a different location than my SQL Server Agent.
I defined my job as PowerShell type in the Step properties of MSSMS and defined the following command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "myserver"   -ScriptBlock {
      try
       {
         C:\...\......\myexe.exe  2>&1  -ErrorAction Stop 
        } 
    catch
       {
        Exit 1
        }
    }
```

where myexe.exe is the executable hosted in the drive of a remote server.
When I do that, I get the following error:

```
Message
Unhandled exception. System.Exception: A Forced Exception for testing purpose
At line:3 char:13
+       $res= & C:\........... ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Unhandled excep...testing purpose:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

.....

Thats is the error that was thrown in my .exe, but actually I expect the job to be in error while it is successfull.

So the question is, how can I handle an exception thrown into my myexe.exe file and catch it into my SQL Agent Job? 
I expect the sql agent job being in error and having my thrown exeption messsage written in the output.

Thans a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
$FilePath = "C:\...\.exe"
$ArgumentList = "your args if you need"
$consoleOutput = (cmd /s /c "$FilePath $ArgumentList")
```

Do not use "-ErrorAction Stop "